# $\cos x=\frac{(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}{2}=\frac{e^{(i-i) x}}{2}=\frac{e^{0}}{2}=\frac 12$

Tags: trigonometry

Something seems amiss here. What am I doing wrong? Is it permissible to add exponents with a variable? $$\cos x=\frac{(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}{2}=\frac{e^{(i-i) x}}{2}=\frac{e^{0}}{2}=\frac 12$$

Comment: Hint: $2^2+2^2 \ne 2^{2+2}$.

Comment: It's clearly not permissable, since you've gotten such a wrong result.

Comment: $ a^b + a^c \neq a^{b + c} $

Answer (score 0):

when I get confused about exponents I think about logs. Somehow those rules are easier to me. You have:

$$ln(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}) $$
vs.
$$ln(e^{(i-i)x}) = (i-i)x = 0$$

Pick one to memorize I guess.